# Gaussian integral and Euler's identity

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers, gaussian-integral

I have noticed that there are two main relationships between the mathematical constants $\pi$ and $e$:

- The Gaussian integral, $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} dx =
     \sqrt{\pi}$
- Euler's identity, $e^{i\pi}+1 = 0$

I know how to prove each of these formulas, but I am curious if there is a conditional proof that can directly prove one statement from the other.

In other words, can the Gaussian integral imply Euler's identity, or vice versa?

Thanks.

Comment: it is very hard to imagine such a connection. Personally, I have no idea if this is possible.